# Is every $T_1$ topological space homeomorphic to a subspace of a separable $T_1$ topological space (with the same cardinality)?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, separable-spaces

Let $X$ be a $T_1$ topological space , then is it true that $X$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of a separable $T_1$ topological space with the same cardinality of $X$ ? If not then what if we drop the same cardinality requirement ?

I know that the statement is true if we don't want the separable space t be $T_1$ , and I also know that the statement is false if we want the separable space to be $T_2$ because of cardinality restriction ( a separable $T_2$ space has cardinality at most $2^{c}$ ). But I can't figure out the $T_1$ case . Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define $\overline X = X \sqcup\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ with the topology generated by these two flavours of open sets.

1. Sets of the form $U \sqcup \{n,n+1,\ldots\}$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$ and open $U \subset X$.
2. Sets of the form $\varnothing \sqcup W$ for any subset $W \subset \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$

Observe that, by construction, every open set of $\overline X$ has some $1,2,3,\ldots$ as an element. Therefore $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is dense in $\overline X$

The singletons of the subspace $X \subset \overline X$ being closed follows from how $X$ is $T_1$.

We can separate any two elements $m,n \in \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ using sets of the form $\varnothing \sqcup \{n\}$ and $\varnothing \sqcup \{m\}$.

We can separate any element $n \in \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $x \in X$ using sets $\varnothing \sqcup \{n\}$ and $U \sqcup \{n+1,n+2, \ldots\}$.

Comment: You could also use $U \sqcup N$ where $N$ is cofinite, I think.

Comment: That's right -- $N$ can have the cofinite or discrete topology, or anything in between!

Comment: N has the discrete topology as a subspace. But the linking of $X$ to $N$ can be almost anything, as long as it's always $T_1$ like.

Comment: Using the cofinite topology on $N$ has the added advantage that the resulting space is compact provided $X$ is compact. This shows that there is no upper bound on the cardinality (nor weight, character etc.) of a separable compact $T_1$ space.